# How to implement a tableview inside a custom tableview cell?

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode. I used to write C programs before, so I am encountering many problems using Xcode.

Now, I am writing an app like "instagram" that shows image and related comments.  All these images and comments are from database, which is not important in my question.

So, please have a look at my design. 
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsF76.png)

This is "one cell setting", at which the apps will keep showing different image and comment while scrolling down and display the another cells.

Firstly, I create a `UITableViewController`, then I enlarge the table view cell to whole view. And I add an `UIImageView` and table view "onto" the cell, thus, this is a custom cell.

Then I create a `UITableViewCell` class to implement this custom cell. I search and found that I can add a subview in this `UITableViewCell` class to show the `UIImage` in my custom cell like:

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x,     cell.contentView.frame.size.height, 20, 20)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

But I can't figure out how to add a `UITableView` as a subview of my custom cell. Say, I can add a code

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:tableView] ;
```

onto my custom cell class, but where can I config the cell contents of this embedded `TableView`? Thus this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ;
```

**So, can someone suggest how can I achieve this? Or there is another approach that can achieve the goal? Thanks for the help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going in the right way.

Create a custom tableview cell derived from `UITableViewCell`, add a `UIImageView` and `UITableView` in the cell's content view. Add tableview's delegate functions in this custom cell class. From your main view when you create an instance of this custom cell, set the datasource for your comments table also.

**EDIT based on comments**

You already have a `UITableViewController` which contains a `UITableView` for displaying images along with comments. This class will contains the delegate methods for handling this datasource. Lets say the name of this class as ContentViewController.

Here in this class you will have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to handle the actual datasource as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId= @"CellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    yourDataObj = [yourDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil){
       cell = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId:yourDataObj]autorelease];
    }
    //Do other cell updations here
    // yourDataObj is a custom class which conatins an array to hold your comments data.
}
```

Now in your CustomCell class, you will have `UIImageView` and `UITableView`. So the init method of this CustomCell class will look like this.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier: (NSString *)reuseIdentifier :(YourDataObj*)cellDisplayData{

     if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

          //You need to alloc and init your imageView and tableView here.
          self.imageView.image = cellDisplayData.image;// or image url whatever
          self.commentsTableDataSource = cellDisplayData.comments; //commentsTableDataSource is property holding comments array

          self.commentsTable.delegate = self;
          self.commentsTable.dataSource = self;
          [self.commentsTable reloadData]; 
     }
 }
```

Also, now in this custom cell class, you can add tableview's delegates and use commentsTableDataSource as your datasource for comments table. Hope you get an idea on how to implement. Please give a try.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply. But I dont quite understand "From your main view when you create an instance of this custom cell, set the datasource for your comments table also" , where should I add the datasource and delegate of the "inner" table view ?

Comment: In your custom cell class. You may add UITableViewDelegate protocol in your custom made cell class .h file and add cellForRowAtIndexPath and other delegate methods inside this.

Comment: Can you give me some example on this? Is that means I can have multiple tableview delegate and datasource method like cellForRowAtIndexPath on one single custom made cell class .h file ?

Comment: Edited the answer..Have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the great help, let me try implement it.